# iOS 7 keyboard issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uitextfield

I am using iOS 7 for my application. In my app I have changed keyboard appearance to '`UIkeyboardApperanceAlert`'. It makes keyboard black. But problem is when app comes from background to foreground, whenever I click in `textField` it first opens keyboard with white color and then it's color turns to black.

Why this is happening?

Comment: Please share some Code with us

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply ,      
textField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;         this is the code I am using for changing keyboard color.

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258765/ios-7-keyboard-color-flash  This is a bug in iOS 7, I had feedback on Apple dev forums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that setting `autocorrectionType` property to `UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo` resolves this issue!

```
self.myTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert is Deprecated in ios7. Use UIKeyboardAppearanceDark instead.

Comment: hi.thanks for replying soon, but UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert is not deprecated and as per your suggestion I have tried for dark but still it is turning from white to black first time when app comes from background to foreground.

Comment: It is depreciated.open UITextInputTraits apple docs, and see under UIKeyboardAppearance.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html

Comment: Hi santhu checked above link, I was wrong. But even if now I am using uiKeyboardAppearanceDark it still gives same problem

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in iOS 7, I had feedback on Apple dev forums.

[iOS 7 Keyboard color flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258765/ios-7-keyboard-color-flash)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

1. Declare the textField in your h. file.
2. On your viewDidLoad / viewDidAppear add this (after allocating and initializing ofcourse):

   [(UITextField *)yourSubView setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];

Or

[yourTextField setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];

Comment: Hey Joe tried your suggestion but no success. It happens only when app comes from background to foreground and that too first time only.